# Re-Distributing Python Toolbox

Tags: arcgis-10.1, python-toolbox, distribution

After reading [this Esri article](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/#/Extending_geoprocessing_through_Python_modules/002z0000002n000000/) on how to distribute Python Toolboxes, I'm wondering how redistribution works?  I have a few toolboxes that are in constant development, but would be useful to my co-workers now.  If I distribute them as the article suggests and they show up in the System Toolbox in ArcMap can I use the same process to update them?  Or is there some extra code that will need to remove the previous version of toolboxes before I distribute the updated versions.

I'm sure I just need to be pointed to a help file where it is all laid out, but I haven't found it yet.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just following the same process again will overwrite your previous toolboxes and should work as a redistribution mechanism. `distutils` doesn't have a built-in delete mechanism (you'd have to go to [`pip`](http://www.pip-installer.org/en/latest/usage.html#pip-uninstall) and friends for that) so this is probably the fastest viable option for redistribution during development.

If you use `bdist_wininst` to distribute `.exe` installers, there will be an uninstaller in the control panel you will need to run first. This is a bit cleaner than `setup.py install`.

Comment: To be sure I understand, for my purposes, using setup.py would be suitable?  If I wanted something cleaner, an exe (made with the bdist_wininst command) would be better, but a toolbox distributed this way would need to be uninstalled before the next version is installed?

Comment: If you want a minimum of user intervention, then `setup.py install` is the easiest. You *could* run the installer multiple times, but I'm not 100% sure it'd then uninstall correctly. Try it out and see?